# How do you have a bot add a reaction using a custom emoji?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to add a custom emoji as a reaction to a message using discord.py version 0.16.12 and I'm unable to get it functional. Here's the code I'm using:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find(':EmojiName:'):
        await bot.add_reaction(message, '<:EmojiName:#EmojiID#>')
```

I've also tried passing the emoji id as a string similar to discord.js `(message, '#EmojiID#')`. Am I supposed to pass the `add_reaction` function an emoji object? And if that's the case, how do I find the specific emoji object from the `get_all_emojis` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the utility function [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get the appropriate [`Emoji` object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#emoji).

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if ':EmojiName:' in message.content:
        emoji = get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='EmojiName')
        await bot.add_reaction(message, emoji)
```

Comment: I was unaware of that function, thank you. I should have seen it in the documentation but I guess I got tunnel vision.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get

Comment: @patrick how to add custom emoji reactions for bot commands reply. for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685273/python-add-custom-reaction-for-message

Comment: @Demotry You should ask a separate question.  I'm not sure how what you're asking differs from this question.

Comment: yes i asked a new question i posted question link in above comment.  what i need is if we use `!ping` command  bot posts  a message or embed with `Pong`  and that embed  should come with reactions added.

Comment: @Demotry Did you try the technique from this answer, using `get` to get the emoji by name from `Client.emojis` or `guild.emojis`?

Comment: yes tried but i using custom emojis or animated emojis like this `<:emoji_name1:emoji_id1>`  and i need to add 3 to 5 emojis to that bot posts. So mostly like a poll bot posts message for commands with pre added reactios.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  I tried same like yours with with some changes `if message.content.startswith("!ping"):`  but it adds reaction for our message `!ping` not for bots message.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_all_emojis' - this is what it says to me

Comment: @zabop There was an API change since this answer was written.  The corresponding attribute is now `bot.emojis` (not a function).

Comment: Made it a different q in the meantime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544309/how-to-make-client-get-all-emojis-work-using-discords-python-api

Comment: Couldn't make it work, explaned it in the new question :)

Comment: It says 'Bot' object does not have attribute 'get_all_emojis'

Comment: @YozyOpto I think the modern version is `emojis`. You should take a look at the documentation though, there have been a few breaking redesigns in the last few years so many old SO answers will be using the old interfaces.

Comment: Now it says 'SequenceProxy' object is not callable

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, folks, I figured it out. You do have to pass it the emoji object itself. For posterity's sake, here's the code I ended up using:

```
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.find(':EmojiName:'):
    for x in client.get_all_emojis():
        if x.id == '#EmojiID#':
            return await client.add_reaction(message, x)
```

Comment: `client.get_all_emojis()` seems deprecated. Asked an updated question here, maybe can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544309/how-to-make-client-get-all-emojis-work-using-discords-python-api