# How do I make my discord.py bot use custom emoji?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I make my bot use my custom emoji in any discord server?

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong :CustomEmoji: {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Example:
If I upload some custom emojis on Server 1  and when we use the `!ping` command (mentioned above) in Server 2 or Server 3 or any server where the bot has access to, it should use the custom emoji.

Result: `Pong with :CustomEmoji:`

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982061/how-do-you-have-a-bot-add-a-reaction-using-a-custom-emoji) for an example of how to get custom emoji using their names.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  your answer in that link is for adding reactions?

Comment: Yes, but the relevant part was using the name of the emoji to get the `discord.Emoji` object.  You can then pretty easily `"Pong {1}: {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message, emoji)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  is there any option to get Emoji ID for animated ?

Comment: Just write a command that takes an emoji: `@bot.command() async def getemoji(emoji: discord.Emoji): print(emoji.id)`

Answer (score 20):

From https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/390:

> It's `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>` for custom emojis.
>
> You can also find the discord.Emoji instance through Server.emojis and
> then cast it to str.

Comment: If you are lazy and want to get the formatted version of `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>` automatically for your emoji, go in Discord and open type in `\:YourEmoji:` (Be sure to replace "YourEmoji with the name of your emoji!)

Discord will automatically return a formatted version of `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>` for your emoji.
source: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/390#issuecomment-625929794

Answer (score 8):

Also for animated ones you do `<a:emoji_name:emoji_id>`

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add the Emoji to **YOUR** (on a server where the bot has access) server.
after adding you type in the Emoji name e.g -> ":myemoji:"
and before the emoji you type an backslash -> (backslah here):myemoji:
and send the message.
When you send the message, you can maby see something like this -> "<:bahn:874911228361854996>", you can use this direct in the bot message
example:

```
await ctx.send(" my custom emoji <:bahn:874911228361854996>")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As we know, every discord bot has nitro privileges when it comes to using emotes. So a bot can access any emoji for all servers it has been added to. What I do is make an API converter for myself with a global emote dictionary.

```
emojis=None

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    global emojis
    if not emojis:
        emojis = {e.name:str(e) for e in ctx.bot.emojis}
    msg = "Pong :CustomEmoji: {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message).replace(':CustomEmoji:',emojis['CustomEmoji'])
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

    if reaction.emoji.id == emoji_id:
        await reaction.message.delete()
```

IMPORTANT: Change the emoji_id, It deletes the message