# Attempting to get a discord bot to react to all messages within a certain channel

Tags: python, discord.py

This script isn't mine. The script is functional, but it only works for one user. I want it to react to all messages sent within a certain channel from any user. I think the problem lies in message.author.id thing, I tried just full out removing the line but it ended up just breaking the entire thing and it wouldn't start up the discord bot. Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
from discord.ext        import commands
from discord.ext.commands    import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("welcome_msg")

async def react(message):
    custom_emojis = [
    ":like:",
    ":emoji:",
    ":emoji:"
    ]
    guild_emoji_names = [str(guild_emoji) for guild_emoji in message.guild.emojis]
    for emoji in custom_emojis:
        if emoji in guild_emoji_names:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 721485450790830111 and \
        message.author.id == 721483699719241748:
            await react(message)```
````

Comment: If you change that conditional to `if message.channel.id == 721485450790830111:` it should work.  You probably just had some formatting wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Custom server emoji can't just be called by name. There is a certain string you need to use to call them:
`<:emoji_name:emoji_id>`

This has all been detailed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982806/python-bot-use-custom-emoji) (or the github issue [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/390)).

This means you need to rewrite your `custom_emojis` list as to be made up of strings formatted like that.

Comment: But the script works, but it only works on one person. I want it to work on all people and messages in a certain channel. However, it only works if I put a users ID into the script.

Comment: Then the answer of @Patrick Haugh should be helpful.