# Discord.py custom emoji reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have done a discord bot and I want to add a custom discord emoji reaction I have this code:

```
    x = await ctx.send(embed=asdf)
    await x.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    await x.add_reaction("once:EmojiID")
```

and when i run the code i have this error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Bot use custom Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982806/python-bot-use-custom-emoji)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom emojis can be send like `<:name:id>`. For example:

```
await ctx.send("<:emoji_1:123456789123456789>")
await message.add_reaction("<:emoji_1:123456789123456789>")
```

Comment: `bot.emojis` returns custom emojis of all guilds that bot is in. So you can get emoji without having to be on the same server.

Comment: Another alternative: `discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name="emoji_1")`. (Edited version of original comment)

Comment: @Weylyn It still not working Some more idea i have tried with the 2 options you give me

Comment: Did you enabled intents?

Comment: I don!'t understand can you explain me? Thanks! @Weylyn

Comment: I am talking about `discord.Intents`. First go to developer portal and enable member and presence intents. Then define your bot object like `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())`.