# Emoji in word list python discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like my bot on discord to send a message when anyone types a word or a sentence. However, that sentence contains an emoji. How can I make the bot see the emoji? If there is no emoji, it works perfectly, the bot sends the wanted message but I can't figure out how to include the emoji.

I'd like the emoji in the part of the following code snippet, where currently I have XXXX.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['Lanfeust got 1 XXXX zombie eye']

        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.channel.send('Nice EYE <@459303124037926915>')
```

I have tried `['I want :apple: apple']` Name of the emoji
I have tried `['I want 908223460097011743 apple']` Id of the emoji

The bot doesn't catch up on it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Bot use custom Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982806/python-bot-use-custom-emoji)

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I am a bit confused by your question. What do you mean by 'make the bot see the emoji'? What is the expected input the user should provide?

Comment: I want my bot to reply something when some use this entire sentence :
I want XXXX apple (XXXX being an emoiji)

It works perfectly if I set it up without emoiji but not with it.

I tried 
word_list = ['I want <:emoji_name:emoji_id> apple'] but it doesn't work.

Comment: One thing you can do as part of debugging is write a message with that emoji yourself and then fetch it using discord.py and try to see what it returns, thats the string you will need to match in your code.

Comment: Try to fetch content of all messages sent to the bot and print them, then send a message with this emoji, copy the content that it prints. Thats the character that represents the emoji. You can replace your XXXX with that character you copied.

Comment: For example using :scream: emoji gives  as the character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode emojis. To get unicode emojis go to https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

and a simple example :

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['I want  apple']
        await ctx.send(random.choice(word_list))
```

Comment: I am not choosing the sentence I want the bot to react and the emoiji that i need my bot to detect is not a traditionnal emoiji, it's a private one.

Comment: U mean u want to add a reaction of custom emoji , right?

Comment: if its a custom emoji you can use it once on a discord channel then copy it and paste iwherever u need to use it.

Comment: yea, to add a custom emoji u should use like `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried and it doesn't work. the bot can't "read" the emoiji.

Comment: can u send me what command or what did u send

Comment: and i just want to tell that unicode emojis , means emoji that are already there for non-nitro users cant be used in `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>` format