# How to add reaction to message sent from bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

My bot sends a embed into a specific channel, after that he should also add 2 reactions to his embed he sent. But i'm kinda stuck at that and searching through website wasn't successful.

````
if '!suggestion' in message.content:
        if "salus insured" in [y.name.lower() for y in message.author.roles]:
            channel = client.get_channel(938973763414921316)
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="User suggestion, vote below!", color=0x03b2f8)
            embedVar.add_field(name="Suggestion", value="```"+substring+"```", inline=False)
            embedVar.add_field(name="Suggested by", value="<@{}>".format(message.author.id))
            embedVar.set_footer(text="Suggestion Poll | @Salus", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/rwBBzGK.png")
            await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
            await message.delete()
````

That's the last part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first retain the message object of the message the bot sends with...

```py
msg = await channel.send("whatever")
```

You can then do things with that message object `msg` as you would any other message.

So in your case:

```py
msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

There are several helpful hints for finding different emoji (e.g. custom emoji) in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982806/how-do-i-make-my-discord-py-bot-use-custom-emoji)