# Cannot Use Custom Emojis On Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

Getting Error When Using Custom Emojis In Discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(intents=intents,command_prefix="$")
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
 if msg.author == client.user:
    return
 else:
    await msg.channel.send("<:doory_fruit:1062084428228206657>")

client.run("MyToken")
```

error 1 when not inputting the id:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrmqS.png)

error 2 when using name and id :
[Image 2 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg4WJ.png)

Any Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my discord.py bot use custom emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982806/how-do-i-make-my-discord-py-bot-use-custom-emoji)

Comment: Perhaps duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982806/how-do-i-make-my-discord-py-bot-use-custom-emoji