# Python add custom reaction for message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add multiple custom reaction for multiple commands Or if we add reaction lists it will add random reactions from that lists. So how to do that.

```
from discord.utils import get
```

Add Emoji by Name.

```
reactions = ['emoji_name_1', 'emoji_name_2', 'emoji_name_3']

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping1(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    reply = await bot.say(msg)
    for emoji_name in reactions:
        emoji = get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name=emoji_name)
        await bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji)
```

---

Add Emoji by ID.

```
reactions = ['a:abc:78768768768', 'a:def:768768766', 'a:ghi:878768787687']

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping2(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    reply = await bot.say(msg)
    for emoji in emojilist:
        await bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji)
```

---

random reaction

```
reactions = ['a:abc:78768768768', 'a:def:768768766', 'a:ghi:878768787687']

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping2(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    reply = await bot.say(msg)
    emojiresult = random.shuffle(reactions)
    for emoji in emojiresult:
        await bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji)
```

Comment: In [the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982339/6779307), you mention that you're trying to have the bot add reactions to its response to a command.  Could you add that code here?

Comment: `a:abc:78768768768` is not the name of one of your emoji, so you can't use it like that.  Instead, just apply that string to `add_reaction` directly: `for emoji in reactions: await bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji)`

Comment: Finally worked both for `Emoji Name` and `Emoji ID` thank you.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  thank you for helping now everything working fine both `Add Emoji by Name` and `Add Emoji by ID` now i trying to make shuffle reaction before adding reactions. but its not working. i added my code above in my question 3rd code.

Comment: `shuffle` changes the list in place, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: So what do i need to do ?

Comment: `emojiresult = random.sample(reactions, k=len(reactions))` instead

Comment: Really amazing thank you. all my 90% question is answered by you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the message that you're sending, then call `add_reaction` on that message, not the `message` passed as an argument to `on_message`

```
from discord.utils import get

reactions = ['123', '456', '']

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(self, ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    reply = await self.bot.say(msg)
    for emoji_id in reactions:
        emoji = get(ctx.server.emojis, name=emoji_id)
        await bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji or emoji_id)  
        # If emoji is None, then emoji_id is likely a unicode emoji
```

Comment: That probably means that `get` failed to find the emoji in `server.emojis`.  You could try `get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name=emoji_name)` instead.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right emoji names?  I went to the Server Settings > Emoji page and used the names under "Alias" without `:` and it works fine.  It won't work for unicode emoji, only custom emoji.  If you want it to work with unicode emoji, you should change it to `bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji or emoji_name)` and use the unicode character in the `reactions` list

Comment: yes worked for custom emoji. can it work in all server if i put custom emoji in 1 server ? what happens if another server has same name emoji.

Comment: Yes, it should work across servers.  If you're worried about emoji of the same name, you should use the emojis `id` instead of its name

Comment: Ok if i add emoji id in `reactions = ['5654654', '65654654', '5656565']` then should i change anything in my code ?

Comment: Change `emoji_name` to `emoji_id` and `name=emoji_name` to `id=emoji_id`

Comment: `await bot.add_reaction(reply, emoji or emoji_id) Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Unknown Emoji`

Comment: For what emojis?  Custom emoji form other servers, unicode emojis, animated emojis...  If it's animated emojis, you may have to switch to rewrite branch, I'm not sure.

Comment: custom animated emojis id

Comment: I think you can send `a:name:id` as text to `add_reaction`, like `add_reaction(reply, "a:myemoji:1234")`.  So that would be `add_reaction(reply, 'a:{0.name}:{0.id}'.format(emoji))`.  I don't think there's a way of differentiating animated emoji from regular ones on async though

Comment: `await bot.add_reaction(reply, 'a:{0.name}:{0.id}'.format(emoji))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Are your animated emoji not showing up in `get_all_emojis()`?  Again, it's possible that the async branch is incapable of dealing with animated emoji.

Comment: I updated my full code in my question above. i added to code 1 works 2nd not working. please check is there any wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for r in reactions:
    await bot.add_reaction(message, r)
```

Comment: [I made a gist](https://gist.github.com/Mehvix/72163652b8cf1b2079616b6dfbdbe974) for it because comments are hard to format

Comment: I getting syntax error i update my new code in my question.