# Discord bot adding reactions to a message discord.py (no custom emojis)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a bot using discord.py add a reaction to a message using discord.py after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982061/how-do-you-have-a-bot-add-a-reaction-using-a-custom-emoji) (which is not what I wanted because I am not using custom emojis) but it ends up giving this error:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: message argument must be a Message`

I tried this code

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def emoji(ctx):
    msg = "working"
    await bot.say(msg)
    reactions = ['dart']
    for emoji in reactions: await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji)
```

Any other related questions here on discord.py are just not helpful for this
Any ideas on how to implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you what the error is: "`message argument must be a Message`"

In the line

```
await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji)
```

`msg` is a string, not a `Message` object.  You need to capture the message you send and then add the reactions to that message:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def emoji(ctx):
    msg = await bot.say("working")
    reactions = ['dart']
    for emoji in reactions: 
        await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji)
```

---

Note that in later versions of `discord.py`, [`add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction) has changed from `bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji)` to `await msg.add_reaction(emoji)`.

Comment: I didn't understand what I had to do. Thank you, it sloved the problem

Comment: What about custom emojis?

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to this as I came across this question wondering how to add reactions in 2022, in case someone else runs into this.

The method displayed in the answer above containing:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def emoji(ctx):
    msg = await bot.say("working")
    reactions = ['dart']
    for emoji in reactions: 
        await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji)
```

**This will no longer work and you will get an error like:**

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

Instead, you'll want to do something like:

```
## EXAMPLE
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hello")
    reaction = ''
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction)
```

For multiple reactions, I've also found that you need to do them separately:

```
## EXAMPLE
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hello")
    reaction1 = ''
    reaction1 = ''
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction1)
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction2)
```

And, for anyone wondering about custom emojis: *(retrieve the emoji ID by typing `\` then clicking the emoji, or you can go to save the file of the custom emoji and copy the default value it gives you.)*

```
## EXAMPLE
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hello")
    reaction1 = "<:yes:965728109200552036>"
    reaction1 = "<:no:965728137122050068>"
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction1)
    await msg.add_reaction(reaction2)
```