# How to have a discord.py bot add reactions to its own message

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot with a verify command, where it sends the bot sends me a dm with a check mark reaction and a "X" reaction, I would then chose the "yes" or "no" and then the bot will give the verified role to the person, if I check yes. Please give me some examples of code for this. Thank You -JJ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot adding reactions to a message discord.py (no custom emojis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636253/discord-bot-adding-reactions-to-a-message-discord-py-no-custom-emojis)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the message object of the bot.

```
message = await ctx.channel.send("This is a message")
```

You can then use the `message.add_reaction()` method which takes an emoji

```
await message.add_reaction("")
```