# How do you make a bot add a custom emoji reaction to its own message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, replit

As far as I know, get_all_emojis has been deprecated and I've been struggling to find a replacement. How do I make a bot add reactions to its own messages with a custom emoji?

What I'm really struggling with is getting the "emoji" variable in the line:

`message.add_reaction(emoji)`

If I can get that, I'm pretty sure the line above would work. How do I do this?

Comment: You forgot to add the code that's not working...

Comment: Pretty much everything online is the code that's not working, I just need code that does

Comment: The marked solution here is an example of the code that doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982061/how-do-you-have-a-bot-add-a-reaction-using-a-custom-emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inform as `emoji`, the code of your custom emoji. To get the code, type in a discord channel `\:emoji_name:`.
The code of a custom emoji has the pattern  `<:name:id>` or `<a:name:id>` in the case of animated emojis.

```py
message.add_reaction("<:Vip:897596558323908678>")
```